# How to get file handle by path?

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi, sysinternals

Sometimes during debugging I need to get handle value for known object (file or dll) opened by debugee. It can help to find who holds this handle.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Son_of_Sam, please don't do such edits. Do you know difference between debugee and debugger? Do you know what is handle in WinAPI? I reverted your inappropriate edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Sysinternals's utilities named [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle) and [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer).

Handle has command line interface and should be used like this:

```
handle [-p <pid>] <file path>
```

To get handle value in Process Explorer:

1. Go to main menu `View -> Select Columns...`
2. Switch to `Handle` tab
3. Check `Handle Value`
4. Open Handle pane for desired process